# How to access AWS Comprehend using aws-sdk-comprehend gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-comprehend, aws-sdk-comprehend

I'm working on getting my Rails app interacting with the AWS Comprehend service for text entity extraction. I'm using the `aws-sdk-comprehend` gem. I have successfully gotten my app working with the AWS Rekognition service for image analysis using the `aws-sdk-rekognition` gem.

I can't seem to get the AWS Comprehend authentication correct as all of my calls result in an `Aws::Comprehend::Errors::InvalidRequestException`.

I have all of the following ENV variables set:

- AWSAccessKeyId
- AWSSecretKey
- AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
- AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

My code looks something like this:

```
class MyApp::Aws::ComprehendService < MyApp::ServiceBase 

  def call
    @credentials = Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWSAccessKeyId'], ENV['AWSSecretKey'])
    @client = Aws::Comprehend::Client.new(region: "us-west-1", credentials: credentials)
    @client.detect_entities({text: "this is a simply little blob of text", language_code: "en"})
  end

end
```

This resulted in `Aws::Comprehend::Errors::InvalidRequestException`. So I also tried:

```
class MyApp::Aws::ComprehendService < MyApp::ServiceBase 

  def call
    # use ENV credential format I've seen in examples...
    @credentials = Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
    @client = Aws::Comprehend::Client.new(region: "us-west-1", credentials: credentials)
    @client.detect_entities({text: "this is a simply little blob of text", language_code: "en"})
  end

end
```

I [found an example](https://ylazarev.com/2020/07/28/5-aws-comprehend-example) that didn't use the `@credential` approach. The example claimed "The initialize method will load the credentials environment variables by itself". So I tried this:

```
class MyApp::Aws::ComprehendService < MyApp::ServiceBase 

  def call
    # ignore setting the credentials
    @client = Aws::Comprehend::Client.new(region: "us-west-1")
    @client.detect_entities({text: "this is a simply little blob of text", language_code: "en"}).
  end

end
```

This also resulted in `Aws::Comprehend::Errors::InvalidRequestException`.

Can you see anything I'm doing wrong? Has anyone had success in using this gem to interact with the Comprehend API?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/Comprehend/Client.html#detect_entities-instance_method) for `Aws::Comprehend::Client#detect_entities`

> If the system detects a document-level error in your input document, the API returns an `InvalidRequestException` error response. For details about this exception, see [Errors in semi-structured documents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/idp-inputs-sync.html#idp-inputs-sync-err) in the Comprehend Developer Guide.

So it appears your usage is not necessarily the issue but rather the input documents themselves.

The response however should include what the actual issue is according to the Developer Guide:

> Document-level errors
>
> If the ClassifyDocument or DetectEntities API operation detects a document-level error in your input document, the API returns an `InvalidRequestException` error response.
>
> In the error response, the **Reason** field contains the value INVALID_DOCUMENT.
>
> The **Detail** field contains one of the following values:
>
> - DOCUMENT_SIZE_EXCEEDED – Document size is too large. Check the size of your file and resubmit the request.
> - UNSUPPORTED_DOC_TYPE – Document type is not supported. Check the file type and resubmit the request.
> - PAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED – Too many pages in the document. Check the number of pages in your file and resubmit the request.
> - TEXTRACT_ACCESS_DENIED_EXCEPTION – Access denied to Amazon Textract. Verify that your account has permission to use the Amazon Textract DetectDocumentText and AnalyzeDocument API operations and resubmit the request.

The `Aws::Comprehend::Errors::InvalidRequestException` object is [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/Comprehend/Errors/InvalidRequestException.html) so it appears you could potentially figure out what is wrong via

```
def call
    # use ENV credential format I've seen in examples...
    @credentials = Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
    @client = Aws::Comprehend::Client.new(region: "us-west-1", credentials: credentials)
    begin
      @client.detect_entities({text: "this is a simply little blob of text", language_code: "en"})
    rescue Aws::Comprehend::Errors::InvalidRequestException => e
      # interrogate the error object here e.g. 
      puts {reason: e.reason, detail: e.detail} 
    end 
  end
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, the `puts` says: `{:reason=>nil, :detail=>nil}`. I ended up using the Google Language service instead. I'm going to leave this question up for a bit to see if an answer emerges.

Comment: @jvillian okay not much more that can be done here although if you still have this connectivity set up maybe try `client.list_entities_detection_jobs` to see if there are even any jobs. I don't use this service but it appears no jobs = no detection.